# Beginner for loop in R not looping

Tags: r, for-loop, max, read.csv

Thanks for reading this entry. I am a beginner R student and have a for() that will not loop thru all of my entries.

```
for (i in 1:9){
maximum<-max(read.csv(paste("data2013010",i,".csv", sep=""),row.names=1))
print(paste("The max of data2013010",i,".csv"," is", maximum))
}

[1] "The max of data2013010 9 .csv  is 1014.5"
```

I can't seem to get this function to loop thru all 9 values in my vector. My first guess is I may need to utilize a counter, am I on the right track or is my code missing a key element?

*Note: This has to be a for() loop*

Comment: Do you get any error messages when running this? If so, please edit them into your question.

Comment: This looks fine as is. My immediate two thoughts are
1 - Are you running this code exactly as you've shown us?
2 - How are you running this code? Are you executing it as a whole, or just the lines within the for? Looks like it's only running the last case.
3 - Depending on your editor it might be doing all of them but only printing the last one. Try placing a "\n" at the end of your print string.

Comment: This looks fine. Can you post a sample of the data? Are you sure, there are no errors / warnings.

Comment: `...loop thru all 9 values in my vector. ` Did you mean, find maximum of all values in each of the 9 data frames? I am a bit curious to understand what you are finally trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the whole `for` loop? Seems to work fine for me when I try to recreate your problem.

Also, if you're just starting with R, I'd recommend learning the tools from the `tidyverse` package. They make your code much simpler and easier to read (and find bugs in).

For example, your `for` loop can be rewritten in the following way using tidyverse:

```
# Put names of all .csv files that start with "data2013010" into a vector called "data_files"

data_files <- list.files() %>% 
  str_extract('^data2013010\\d+\\.csv') %>% 
  na.omit()

# Iterate across the data_files vector to find the maximum of each element

purrr::map(data_files, ~ read_csv(.x) %>%
             max(.))
```